# Ruby: How to generate CSV files that has Excel-friendly encoding

Tags: ruby, excel, csv, encoding, export-to-csv

I am generating CSV files that needs to be opened and reviewed in Excel once they have been generated. It seems that Excel requires a different encoding than UTF-8.

Here is my config and generation code:

```
csv_config = {col_sep: ";", 
              row_sep: "\n", 
              encoding: Encoding::UTF_8
             }

csv_string = CSV.generate(csv_config) do |csv|
  csv << ["Text a", "Text b", "Text æ", "Text ø", "Text å"]
end
```

When opening this in Excel, the special characters are not being displayed properly:

```
Text a  Text b  Text Ã¦ Text Ã¸ Text Ã¥
```

Any idea how to ensure proper encoding?

Comment: Try putting `# encoding: UTF-8` as your Ruby file's first line (second if you have a hash-bang line, `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`). I believe you are *writing* in UTF-8, but the Ruby source file is taken to be encoded as US_ASCII. (With Ruby 2.0+, source encoding defaults to UTF-8)

Comment: I am using `ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]` so I suppose that means that my installation is already defaulting to UTF-8.

Comment: No experience with Ruby. But Excel can open semicolon delimited CSV files which are UTF-8 encoded. But the file must have a BOM at its beginning. And whether the semicolon can be used as delimiter is locale dependent. So the best approach is to use tabulator delimited CSV and those UTF-16LE encoded. This should be most locale independent.

Comment: What Excel are you using? I had no trouble getting the special characters to display in Excel 2013.

Comment: Another hint: With the [axlsx-gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/axlsx/) it is easy to create direct a xlsx-files.

Answer (score 34):

Excel understands UTF-8 CSV if it has BOM. That can be done like:

#### Use CSV.generate

```
# the argument of CSV.generate is default string
csv_string = CSV.generate("\uFEFF") do |csv|
  csv << ["Text a", "Text b", "Text æ", "Text ø", "Text å"]
end
```

#### Use CSV.open

```
filename = "/tmp/example.csv"

# Default output encoding is UTF-8
CSV.open(filename, "w") do |csv|
  csv.to_io.write "\uFEFF" # use CSV#to_io to write BOM directly 
  csv << ["Text a", "Text b", "Text æ", "Text ø", "Text å"]
end
```

Comment: Thanks the CSV.open solution worked perfectly for me! Slightly cleaner solution than other answers.

Comment: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `to_io' for #<StringIO:0x00000001d0c540> :(

Comment: Thanks for also saying how with CSV.open

Comment: This works for me even when I open on excel online, thanks!

Comment: FYI: `\uFEFF` is BOM for UTF-16. Use `\xEF\xBB\xBF` for UTF-8. Here is [list of BOMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding) for UTF encodings.

Comment: if it has currency symbols like '₹ 60' AND '€ 70' it will not work so please check this answer it might be helpful for this scenario

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73455335/6425718

Comment: this is the only thing that worked for me. I wish we could just do "CSV.open(filename, "w", encoding: "bom|utf-8")". That works while reading the file but it doesn't while writing to the output file.

Comment: Just for the record; Microsoft also says this in their docs:
> You can open a CSV file encoded with UTF-8 normally if it was saved with BOM (Byte Order Mark). Otherwise, you can open it through either of the following ways.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/opening-csv-utf-8-files-correctly-in-excel-8a935af5-3416-4edd-ba7e-3dfd2bc4a032

Answer (score 32):

The top voted answer from @joaofraga worked for me, but I found an alternative solution that also worked - no UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 transcoding required.

From what I've read, Excel, can indeed handle UTF-8, but for some reason, it doesn't recognize it by default. But if you **add a BOM to the beginning of the CSV data**, this seems to cause Excel to realise that the file is UTF-8.

So, if you have a CSV like so:

```
csv_string = CSV.generate(csv_config) do |csv|
  csv << ["Text a", "Text b", "Text æ", "Text ø", "Text å"]
end
```

just add a BOM byte like so:

```
"\uFEFF" + csv_string
```

In my case, my controller is sending the CSV as a file, so this is what my controller looks like:

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.csv do
      #  add BOM to force Excel to realise this file is encoded in UTF-8, so it respects special characters
      send_data "\uFEFF" + csv_string, type: :csv, filename: "csv.csv"
    end
  end
end
```

I should note that UTF-8 itself **does not require or recommend a BOM at all**, but as I mentioned, adding it in this case seemed to nudge Excel into realising that the file was indeed UTF-8.

Comment: Don't be confused like i was, older Excel does not work (2010 and above)

Answer (score 11):

You should switch the encoding to `ISO-8859-1` as following:

```
CSV.generate(encoding: 'ISO-8859-1') { |csv|  csv << ["Text á", "Text é", "Text æ"] }
```

For your context, you can do this:

```
config = {
  col_sep: ';',
  row_sep: ';',
  encoding: 'ISO-8859-1'
}

CSV.generate(config) { |csv|  csv << ["Text á", "Text é", "Text æ"] }
```

I had the same issue and that encoding fixed.

Comment: The answer above worked for me, but only after I removed the `col_sep` and `row_sep` arguments. Just the `encoding: 'ISO-8859-1'` was all I needed. For context, the specific issue I was having was `é` characters appearing as `Ã©`

Comment: Good catch Greg, I will update the example without the context.

Comment: yeah, sure, 8859-1 good for everything yay, try writing some japanese or arabic characters in a CSV file like that. OP asked specifically for UTF-8, so why advise him to go decades back in time?

Answer (score 0):

```
config = {

  encoding: 'ISO-8859-1'
}

CSV.generate(config) { |csv|  csv << ["Text á", "Text é", "Text æ"] }
```

Comment: Would you like to augment your code-only answer with some explanation?

Comment: OP asked for UTF-8 specifically, not 8859-1 aka ANSI

Answer (score 0):

With https://github.com/gtd/csv_builder, I had to:

In the controller action:

```
@output_encoding = 'UTF-8'
send_data "\uFEFF" + render_to_string(), type: :csv, filename: @filename
```

Atop the `csv.csvbuilder` template:

```
faster_csv.to_io.write("\uFEFF")
```

I don't know why I had to add the BOM twice, but it did not work with either one on its own.