# Arabic text coming as symbols in MS Office

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, encoding

In windows 7 Arabic texts coming as symbols when exporting a file from my project. I'm using MS office 2007 and my project is in rails. is it encoding problem or something else? I'm attaching the screen shot here[image: excel file screen shot]

```
    filename = "Print Batch CSV- #{Time.now.to_date.to_s}.csv"
send_data(csv_string, :type => 'text/csv; charset=utf-8; header=present', :filename => filename)
```

this is the code for writing csv.

issue is with the MIME type or encoding?

Comment: This worked for me

`send_data("\uFEFF" + csv_string, :type => 'text/csv; charset=utf-8; header=present', :filename => filename)`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47098902/6856611