# Some Currency symbols not showing in Ms excel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, character-encoding, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm generating a CSV like this

```
::CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
  csv << ['Date', 'Transaction', 'Order Total', 'Wallet Amount', 'Wallet Balance']
    fetch_data.each do |data_response|
    data_response.wallet_amount = "₹40"
    csv_data = { date: data_response.display_date} 
        .merge(data_response.to_h.except(*skip_attributes))
    csv << csv_data.values
  end
 end
```

Now after generating it when I open it in Linux it works fine but not for Ms-Excel. Currency symbols like **₹**, **€** not showing properly.

Here is the sample picture from Ms-Excel

[image]

and when i tried to convert it in ***iso*** format like this

```
::CSV.generate(headers: true, encoding: 'ISO-8859-9')
```

the error i got is

> Encoding::UndefinedConversionError (U+20B9 from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-9)

is there any way that my euro and INR symbols can show on Ms-excel

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'₹ €'.encode( 'utf-8').decode('cp1254')` returns `'â‚¹ â‚¬'`.

Comment: @JosefZ so how can i tackle this ?

Comment: I think that Excel has _File_ -> _Import_ function where you can define encoding of input `.csv`  file. Determine `UTF-8`.

Comment: @JosefZ but we are sending this csv to non-technical persons

Comment: Please check this: https://superuser.com/search?q=excel+csv+bom

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Excel mangles Diacritics in .csv files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155097/microsoft-excel-mangles-diacritics-in-csv-files)

Comment: yeah it is helpful I'm going to upvote it but now I'm sharing the exact solution @JosefZ

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

So finally I solve this by attaching a UTF-8 BOM as a prefix to my file
Here is the code

```
with_utf8_bom( ::CSV.generate(headers: true, encoding: Encoding::UTF_8) do |csv|
      csv << ['Date', 'Transaction', 'Order Total', 'Wallet Amount', 'Wallet Balance']
      fetch_data.each do |data_response|
        csv_data = { date: data_response.display_date }.merge(data_response.to_h.except(*skip_attributes))
        csv_data[:wallet_amount] = '€70'
        # debugger
        csv << csv_data.values
      end
    end )

private

  def with_utf8_bom(content)
    "\uFEFF" + content
   end
```

I hope this will help someone to tackle this issue.